# Applying styles to multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

Why doesnt the following apply the css rules to both elements?

```
var prevElem = $('<a href="#" class="'+ settings.prev +'" />').text('Prev');
var nextElem = $('<a href="#" class="'+ settings.next +'" />').text('Next');
container.append(prevElem, nextElem);
$(prevElem, nextElem).css('top', container.height()/2);
```

Its only applied to prevElem.

**Please note that the dynamic elements have been added to the DOM (with their classes) so they are there.**

Comment: Have you declared settings.next class??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you need, you must call `add()` method.

```
var prevElem = $('<a href="#" class="'+ settings.prev +'" />').text('Prev');
var nextElem = $('<a href="#" class="'+ settings.next +'" />').text('Next');

prevElem.add(nextElem).appendTo(container).css('top', container.height()/2);
```

Reason you can't join arrays by providing them as parameters to `jQuery`, is that there is simply no such API. And there shouldn't be because it would make it impossible to implement [jQuery( selector [, context] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) which searches for elements within context.
Check out [$.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) for what you attempted to do.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, great explanation. Your get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be:

```
prevElem.add(nextElement).css('top', container.height()/2);
```

If you have a look at the [documentation of `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) you will see that you cannot create a jQuery object with two elements the way you tried. Read the documentation, there is no need to *guess* how it works.